# For $\phi$ as a homomorphism not onto show not normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am just a little unclear about what I am supposed to do here.

Let $\phi: G $ to $J$ be a homomorphism onto all of $J$. Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and let $K=\phi(H)$ be the image of $H$ under the homomorphism.

I have showed that K is normal to J. I now need to provide an example that K could not be normal to G if $\phi$ is not onto.

Do I need to find a G,J,K, and H such that it there is a homomorphism but it is not onto? Is this the right path? Because if it is then I have thought and thought and I am stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Let $J$ be a group and let $G$ be a subgroup of $J$ that is not a normal subgroup. Then the inclusion homomorphism of $G$ with $H=G$ satisfies the condition. The inclusion homomorphism is the homomorphism $i:G\to J$ such that $i(g)=g$ for all $g\in G$.

Comment: thank you very much, but what does the inclusion homomorphism mean? the same as the identity mapping?

Comment: @Jack See edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the inclusion of $A_4$ into $A_5$. Take any normal subgroup of $A_4$. Its image cannot be normal in $A_5$ because $A_5$ is simple.

Comment: This is a nice answer, although I feel like using the fact that $A_{5}$ is simple is a bit heavy handed for this exercise. I also feel like it misses the point in a sense, since this exercise shows that if $\phi$ is not onto, you can't effectively leverage the normality of $H$ in $G$. +1 from me anyway.

Comment: @AWertheim, you're right, it is a bit overkill, especially when Matt's answer is so much simpler.