# Suppose that $N_1$ is a normal subgroup of $G_1$. Is the image $f(N_1)$ of $N_1$ a normal subgroup of $G_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f:G_1 \to G_2$ be a homomorphism between multiplicative groups.

Suppose that $N_1$ is a normal subgroup of $G_1$. Is the image $f(N_1)$ of $N_1$ a normal subgroup of $G_2$?

Comment: How is your question related to the title? And have you tried some examples?

Comment: Also, your title is in correct, it's the opposite that's true. Take $H$ to be the trivial subgroup.

Comment: No. Take a group $G$ which has a non-normal subgroup $N ≤ G$. Then take $G_1 = N$, $G_2 = G$ and $f = \text{inclusion}$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1016085/589.

Answer (score 1):

If $N\subset G_2$ is normal, then also is $f^{-1}(N)$ as the kernel of $G_1\to G_2\to G_2/N$.

Howver the other direction, which is the one you are asking for, is not true. Every subgroup (in particular the non-normal ones) is image of a normal subgroup under a homomorphism. Just consider inclusion of the subgroup itself or of the normalizer.